# Extracting 7-segment display numbers within a video using Pytesseract

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm running an experiment involving a chemical reaction in which the resistance of the solution oscillates over time. Annoyingly I didn't have the equipment on hand to record the resistance values directly from the multimeter I was using but have recorded videos of the reaction solution next to the multimeter in clear view.

[image: 1]

I am able to crop the videos easily to ensure the screen of the multimeter is the only thing present in all frames of the video.
I'm a somewhat competent user of python within jupyter lab, but I've never used any OCR engine before. How would I extract the values reported from the multimeter using pytesseract?

This is an image from the video that has been cropped appropriately

[image: 2]

Comment: With a fixed camera ? Don't use Tesseract for such a job. That would be as training an AI to learn to multiply two numbers; not only that is too much work for a simple task, but moreover, it won't be reliable enough (no OCR is 100% reliable). Plus the background, the font, and the absence of context make it a hard task for an OCR. Why don't you just count the average (or medium) value of each of the 7 segments of the digits and get the digits from there? (I know it may sound tedious. Especially if that is a one-time task. And I hope it is a one-time task

Comment: because if not, it is about time you buy the cheapest arduino and measure directly the resistance with it). But you will probably suffer more to try to calibrate tesseract to do this kind of thing, than to just use a paint-like software to draw 7×4 mask (they don't even need to be accurate. As long as you grab some dozen pixel belonging to each segment)

Comment: for future experiments, *do* get a multimeter with digital communications ability. those can be USB or infrared (with USB cable) for live communication, or they can carry memory for logging and readout. test equipment is easily available to serve your goal.

Comment: since tesseract loves to fail on hard cases, you must consider other OCR packages. if all else fails, define "sampling lines" that cross each segment of the display, then sample those, and analyze those 1D signals for whether they show a dip (segment black). that'd be a brute force but reliable approach. it does require neither the meter nor the camera to be moving, and the lighting needs to be constant too. varying lighting can be handled but if the camera/meter moves, that'll be a lot more work.

Comment: if you can provide the complete video, I might give it a try. for best results, ping me (add a comment) in... 8 hours. I might forget otherwise.

Comment: Hi chris, I really appeciate the help! To save you the hassle I'm gonna take the easy route and use an arduino of a raspberry pi to collect values from the multimeter instead, thanks again

Comment: @DanielRindfuss there's no hastle in stack overflow, everybody is here because it's fun. Your problem is extra fun even. I would love to see Christoph's answer to this, I might even answer it on the easter holidy if I have enough free time

Comment: well "lines" were a misstep. just defining an area per segment is good enough. from all the segment bits, one can figure out the digits/letters

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz how would you get the digits though? The ROI seems quite small and blurred. I can imagine something with `cv2.contourArea` or `cv2.countNonZero` might work, given that the digits are easily separable by only using that information (maybe 2 and 5 not really? 0 and 9 as well?). I'm more interested in the pre-processing that could be applied.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz at the end of this comment is an icloud link containing 2 videos, one full resolution, and another is cropped down to only the multimeter screen. Either can be saved and edited as you wish. Let me know if you make any progress. Anyone else keen to try, go for it! It would only be helping me and I'd be glad to be of some entertainment! https://share.icloud.com/photos/016Zo14_nBO7XdKm1JYsl5Ihg The videos will be available once uploaded, shouldn't take long.

Comment: I admit, my idea is very typing-intensive (defining sample points, defining evaluations for the segments, defining symbols from segments, ...). it might have been quicker to deploy a dumb little CNN but I am not practiced in DL...

Comment: here's the output: https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/6d5bcfef498fc4410e2b0b0dcbf11762 there will be `?` any time a bunch of segments are "marginal" or don't form a symbol I anticipated (also when they all switch/update). the `k` SI prefix and some decimal points are especially hard because they are blurry. and of course the reflections from people moving around ruin a few parts. you'll want to edit this text file. -- with training-oriented methods (filter bank or neural network) this could be solved with more success.

Comment: the "breakage" patterns in the file are somewhat obvious and easy to fix for a human. missing decimal point when it's `0555k` or the `k` fluctuates while the display shows `0.555`. you could even try dumping this text file into chatgpt 4 (maybe with code interpreter), ask it to clean it up. you should definitely do a diff of the result to the input, to make sure it's not breaking the data completely.

Comment: these are the sample areas I used. a bunch are background, to estimate lighting variations (and tolerate some of the reflections). https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1kTu.png

Comment: if I had enough practice with DL, I think training a simple model to scrape the display should be fairly easy todo... maybe someone like that will come along.